# ufw enable port 3306 for mysql access, but can not ping

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

[image]

[image]

above are my ufw status

but if I ping 3306 at

https://ping.eu/port-chk/

it reports the port is closed

your comment welcome

Comment: Service is not listening on a public interface, only on loopback.  Please reproduce text rather than screenshots of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default mysqld config is binding to 127.0.0.1 (localhost).
You need to modify bind-address to 0.0.0.0  for listening all interfaces in file mysqld.cnf (/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf)

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```